No route found for "POST /login" (from "http://xx.net/authentication/signin")
I'm having trouble deploying my web application on a server. I have created an API in Symfony using various components and a client in Angular with npm. It works perfectly fine on my local machine, but when I try to run it on the server using Apache, I run into an issue. When I try to log in, I get this error:
No route found for "POST /login" (from "http://xx.net/authentication/signin")
This is called from the client. When I access xx.net/api, the Symfony page displays without errors, so that seems to be working fine. However, there’s likely an issue with the proxy, which I can't figure out how to resolve. Can someone please help?
Here’s my Apache configuration:
server@xx:~$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/xx.net.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin xx@gmail.com
ServerName xxnet
DocumentRoot /var/www/xx.net

# Přesměrování požadavků na /api do /var/www/xx.net-api
Alias /api /var/www/xx.net-api/public

# Nastavení oprávnění pro přístup k souborům API
<Directory /var/www/xx.net-api>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    #SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    #SetHandler "proxy:fcgi:///run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock"
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/xx.net>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xx-error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_xx.log combined

server@xx:/var/www/xx.net-api$ sudo -su www-data php bin/console debug:router api_user_login
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                       |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | api_user_login                                              |
| Path         | /api/login                                                  |
| Path Regex   | #^/api/login$#sD                                            |
| Host         | ANY                                                         |
| Host Regex   |                                                             |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                         |
| Method       | POST                                                        |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                   |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                             |
| Defaults     | _controller: App\Controller\Api\UserController::loginAction |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler     |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+

Local working configuration:
PS C:\Users\x\git\x-cli> npm start

> x@1.1.1 start
> ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --port 4208

(node:13524) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4208, open your browser on http://localhost:4208/ **
 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active[HPM] Proxy created: /api  ->  http://127.0.0.1:9000
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events:  [ 'error', 'close' ]
[HPM] Proxy created: /api-prototyp  ->  http://172.20.2.110:82
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events:  [ 'error', 'close' ]
[HPM] Proxy created: /server-api  ->  https://api-dev.iotian.cz
[HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/server-api" ~> "/api"
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events:  [ 'error', 'close' ]


 php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public    ^

